# How to set undo-outer-limit in emac gdb

Tags: emacs, gdb

I used gdb 7.6's undo feature in emacs 24.3, and got the following warnings. It suggests me to set `undo-outer-limit' to be a larger value. How should I set the variable to a correct value? How large can emacs support?

```
Warning (undo): Buffer `*gud-foo*' undo info was 13351087 bytes long.
The undo info was discarded because it exceeded `undo-outer-limit'.

This is normal if you executed a command that made a huge change
to the buffer.  In that case, to prevent similar problems in the
future, set `undo-outer-limit' to a value that is large enough to
cover the maximum size of normal changes you expect a single
command to make, but not so large that it might exceed the
maximum memory allotted to Emacs.

If you did not execute any such command, the situation is
probably due to a bug and you should report it.

You can disable the popping up of this buffer by adding the entry
(undo discard-info) to the user option `warning-suppress-types',
which is defined in the `warnings' library.
```

Comment: `I used gdb 7.6's undo feature, and got the following warnings` This is a warning from Emacs. It has *nothing* to do with GDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `undo-outer-limit` from the default value of 24,000,000 (see [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html)) by setting it in your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```lisp
;; increase undo-outer-limit to 72MB, 3x default value
(setq undo-outer-limit 72000000)
```

64-bit Emacs should be able to handle much larger values (see [this discussion of supported file sizes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsFileSizeLimit)) but as the warning says, very high undo memory usage may indicate a bug, so it's probably more sensible to set it as high as you find yourself needing it and not much farther.

Note that if you habitually work with files that would have been considered large in 2003 (i.e., files > 10MB), you may also want to increase `large-file-warning-threshold`:

```lisp
;; increase large-file-warning-threshold to 30MB, 3x default value
(setq large-file-warning-threshold 30000000)
```